# How to Make Tkinter Entries from An Entry Box into A Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a entry box that allows users to input multiple integers separated by commas. How do I get the entries from this entry box into a python list which I can store as a variable.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.If you require specific examples of code please  reply and ask me.

Comment: Please add some code (the button definitions, to be specific) to your question, so we can better understand your question and possibly identify the issue(s). Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before adding your code.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different ways that you could do this. The first and "simplest" is using `split()`.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    print(entry.get().split(" "))

entry = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, text="Print", command=command)

entry.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the above snippet we simply call `split()` on the value of the `Entry` (which is returned from `entry.get()`) using `" "` (the space character) as our delimiter. So every word separated by a space character is placed into it's own element in the `list`.

We could do this with any delimiter, if for example you wanted to have each element separated by a comma character, you would simply update the delimiter to `","` or if you wanted to remove the space as well `", "`.

---

Another way of doing this, which I would argue is more user friendly is to have a different `Entry` widget for each element of the list.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

labels = [Label(root, text="Value1:"), Label(root, text="Value2:"), Label(root, text="Value3:"), Label(root, text="Value4:"), Label(root, text="Value5:")]
entries = [Entry(root), Entry(root), Entry(root), Entry(root), Entry(root)]

for label, entry in zip(labels, entries):
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()

def command():
    print([entry.get() for entry in entries])

Button(root, text="print", command=command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will cycle through each of the `Entry` widgets whenever the `Button` is pushed and return a `list` of their contents.